# How to arrange and sort same items from different columns under one column

Tags: sorting

Can someone please help me how I can arrange to display the same items from different columns under one column?
Here's what my data currently looks like:
[Current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOYWQ.png)

and here's how I would want it to look like :

[Preferred layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOhVy.png)

So all the federal items are under Column A, all Social items are under Column E etc...

Thank you

I removed all the Federal 37 (ColumnL) items that had 0 value, and started manually (Cut/Paste) shifting the items to the left.